# When flipping a card with css the backside shows but it is not usable

Tags: html, css, reactjs, forms, sass

I wanted to create a css flip card effect.
The front side is a login form and the backside is a registration form (with 2 input fields more).
The animation shows correctly the front and back (even if the transition looks a bit weird) but when the backside is facing the user, I cannot click or interact with the form. I am working in React with scss modules and here is the code. The animation occurs when the "create an account" button is clicked. I set a state and add conditionally a .flip class using [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames).

```
const formCardClass = cx({
    formCard: true,
    flip: isRegister,
  });
```

Here the render of the component:

```
<div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={formCardClass}>
        <div className={styles.formCardLogin}>
          <FormGroup>
            <h2>Login to your account</h2>
            <InputText type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" />
            <InputText type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
            <Button>Login</Button>
            <p>
              Not registered?{' '}
              <button type="button" onClick={btnClick} className={styles.btn}>
                Create an account
              </button>
            </p>
          </FormGroup>
          <div className={styles.formCardRegister}>
            <FormGroup>
              <h2>Register</h2>
              <InputText type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
              <InputText type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
              <InputText
                type="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Password"
              />
              <InputText
                type="password"
                name="password2"
                placeholder="Confirm password"
              />
              <Button>Register</Button>
              <p>
                Already registered?{' '}
                <button type="button" onClick={btnClick} className={styles.btn}>
                  Login here
                </button>
              </p>
            </FormGroup>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the stylesheet:

```
@import 'scss/config';

.container {
  padding: 5rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 60vh;
  column-gap: 5rem;

  background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba($color-primary, 0.5),
      rgba($color-primary, 0.5)
    ),
    url(../../assets/images/background-img.jpg);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 4%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 96%, 0 100%);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  perspective: 50rem;
}

.formCard {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: $border-radius-default;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;

  &Login,
  &Register {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateY(var(--flip-front, 0));
  }

  &Register {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }

  & p {
    color: $color-primary;
    transform: translateY(-0.8rem);
    justify-self: center;
  }
}

.btn {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: inherit;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    color: $color-primary-dark;
  }

  &:active {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.flip {
  --flip-front: -180deg;
}
```

I hope I could explain the issue. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are always rendering the front form before the back form, even when you are showing the back form. I'm wondering if this is not the reason why you can't interact with the second form because your mouse events are sent to the first form. If you're "create account" handler set a state, you could use that state to hide the first form using conditional rendering just to test if that solves the problem

Comment: That's not the problem. The forms are rendered one after the other but they are present in the page as a front and back of a card. CSS handles what's in the front and what's in the back as if it was a 3d element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested, after a good night sleep and some more patience I solved it.
I did a mistake in closing the div tags, so the back of the form card was a child of the front side instead of being adjacent.
(I should have closed the formCardLogin div after the first FormGroup):

```
<div className={styles.formCardLogin}>
          <FormGroup>
            <h2>Login to your account</h2>
            <InputText type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" />
            <InputText type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
            <Button>Login</Button>
            <p>
              Not registered?{' '}
              <button type="button" onClick={btnClick} className={styles.btn}>
                Create an account
              </button>
            </p>
          </FormGroup>
----->  </div>
```

Then in the stylesheet I created another variable that when the class flip is active turns the backside back to 0deg.

```
.flip {
  --flip-front: -180deg;
  --flip-back: 0deg;
}
```